# Firefox/Chrome - unexpected margin?

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

Chrome/Firefox.

An unexpected margin appears above the breadcrumb. If you look at other pages on the website, you will see breadcrumb correctly positioned.

Any idea what's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I was using Notepad++ and changed from ANSI encoding to UTF-8 for support of foreign characters. But that seems to have messed everything up. Switched it from "UTF-8 without BOM" back to Ansi, and it removed all the unexpected whitespaces which were causing the margin.

Comment: That was putting you into quirks mode. This was not a problem with Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try to comment this and test:

```
margin:5px 0px;
```